# Why isn't image_transport_plugins available on ROS2 dashing?

Tags: ros2, ros-crystal, image-transport

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello, I've been using image_transport on ROS crystal but now I would like to upgrade to dashing. I noticed ros-dashing-image-transport exists, but ros-dashing-image-transport-plugins doesn't. Why so, if it was available on crystal?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/329514/why-isn%27t-image_transport_plugins-available-on-ros2-dashing?/) by [amargs](https://answers.ros.org/users/41508/amargs/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2019-07-29

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Apologies, this was likely me missing the package on the checklist when doing the release.  I'll get it released for you.

---

Originally posted by [mjcarroll](https://answers.ros.org/users/9/mjcarroll/) with karma: 6414 on 2019-07-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [amargs](https://answers.ros.org/users/41508/amargs/) on 2019-07-30**:
Thank you! When will it be released?

**Comment by [mjcarroll](https://answers.ros.org/users/9/mjcarroll/) on 2019-08-28**:
This has been released now.